# Implementing shell in C input redirection problem

Tags: c, linux, shell, file-descriptor

Pipes works properly. Out redirection works too and I can combine both.
But in redirection just works if there's no pipe.

it works: `command1 | command2 > file` 
it doesn't work: `command1 < file | command2`

For second example I don't get where the error is, in my mind this is the procedure: there are 2 command calls, first it takes  `command1 < file`   and **first** variable is set to 1 so `dup2( tuberia[1], STDOUT_FILENO );` is executed and it replaces write pipe for stdout, we have **rin** variable set to 1 so stdin is replaced  by the opened file. The output of the exec should be in the write pipe.

Secondly we have **rin** set to 0 and **last** to 1, then `dup2( input, STDIN_FILENO );` is executed and we read from the read pipe (input, tuberia[0]), for some reason this isn't working like that. I probably don't understand something important about file descriptors, thanks for reading and pleaaaaaaaase help :I

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static char* args[512];
int input,first,last,rout,rin;
char* file;
pid_t pid;
static char line[1024];
static int n = 0;


static char* skipwhite(char* s)
{
    while (isspace(*s)) ++s;
    return s;
}

static void split(char* cmd)
{
    cmd = skipwhite(cmd);
    char* next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
    int i = 0;
 
    while(next != NULL) {
        next[0] = '\0';
        args[i] = cmd;
        ++i;
        cmd = skipwhite(next + 1);
        next = strchr(cmd, ' ');
    }
 
    if (cmd[0] != '\0') {
        args[i] = cmd;
        next = strchr(cmd, '\n');
        next[0] = '\0';
        ++i; 
    }
 
    args[i] = NULL;
}

void command(char* cmd)                                                 
{
    split(cmd);

    //BUILT INS
    if (args[0] != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0) {
                exit(0);
            }
        n += 1;
    }

    int tuberia[2];

    pipe(tuberia);  
    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {

        if (first == 1 && last == 0 && input == 0) {
            dup2( tuberia[1], STDOUT_FILENO );
        } else if (first == 0 && last == 0 && input != 0) {
            dup2(input, STDIN_FILENO);
            dup2(tuberia[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        } else{
            dup2( input, STDIN_FILENO );
            if(rout == 1)   
            {   
                int out = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, 0666);
                dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(out);
            }
        }
        if(rin == 1)
        {   
            int in = open(file, O_RDONLY);
            dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(in);
        }
        if (execvp(args[0],args) == -1) 
            fprintf (stderr, "ERROR: EXEC FAILED!!\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    if (input != 0) 
        close(input);
 
    close(tuberia[1]);
 
    if (last == 1)
    {
        close(tuberia[0]);
    }
 
    input = tuberia[0];
    
}

void inhandler(char* cmd)
{
    char* in = strchr(cmd, '<');
    if(in != NULL)
    {
        rin = 1;
        file = in + 1;
        file = skipwhite(file);
        in[0] = '\0';
        strtok(file, "\n");
    }
    else rin = 0;
}

void outhandler(char* cmd)
{
    char* out = strchr(cmd, '>');
    if(out != NULL)
    {
        rout = 1;
        file = out + 1;
        file = skipwhite(file);
        out[0] = '\0';
        strtok(file, "\n");
    }
    else rout = 0;
}

void filter()
{
    input = 0;
    first = 1;
 
    char* cmd = line;
    char* next = strchr(cmd, '|'); 

    while (next != NULL) 
    {
        *next = '\0';
        last=0; 

        inhandler(cmd);
        command(cmd);
 
        cmd = next + 1;
        cmd=skipwhite(cmd);
        next = strchr(cmd, '|'); 
        first = 0;
    }
    last=1; 

    outhandler(cmd);
    inhandler(cmd);
    command(cmd);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        wait(NULL);
    n = 0;
}

void  main(void)
{                                                            
    char buf[PATH_MAX];
    while (1) {                                                                     
        printf( "%s : ", getcwd(buf, PATH_MAX)); 
        if (!fgets(line, 1024, stdin)) 
            exit(0);            
        filter();                                               
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a big code dump. Can you explain more clearly what you think _should_ happen to set up `command1 < file | command2` and what you saw when you tried to investigate what _really did_ happen?

Comment: I put the code just in case someone wanted to know some variable meaning, but i'm pretty sure the problem is in the **command** function. I just don't understand why  `command1 | command2` works and with < it doesn't when im doing same thing, im just adding the standard input as a file in the first iteration.